# What is the best way to update the source of a XamDataGrid from a different form?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, infragistics

I have a `XamDataGrid` in my MainWindow which has a `Public Shared List(Of Artikelstammdaten)` as `DataSource`. After opening a few other forms I want to add more data to the `XamDataGrid` with a button click. I thought the easiest way would be just to update the `DataSource`, but I get an Error:

> The reference to an unreleased member requires an object reference.

This is what I have tried:

```vb
    Private Sub Add_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim update = MainWindow.listArtikelstammdaten.Concat(CType(Import.ComparedAccessData, IEnumerable(Of Artikelstammdaten)))
        dgArticleMasterData.DataSource = update
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Check the following post about updating of the collection on a background thread: [DataSource Property](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.datapresenter~infragistics.windows.datapresenter.datapresenterbase~datasource)

Comment: Is `dgArticleMasterData` defined in a different window than `Add_Click`? Your question lacks details.

Comment: @mm8 dgArticleMasterData is defined in the MainWindow and Add_Click is in a different Window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `dgArticleMasterData` is defined in the `MainWindow` class, you need to get a reference to the `MainWindow` instance to be able to access it.

You should be able to find it in the `Application.Current.Windows` collection:

```
Private Sub Add_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim update = MainWindow.listArtikelstammdaten.Concat(CType(Import.ComparedAccessData, IEnumerable(Of Artikelstammdaten)))

    Dim window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of MainWindow).FirstOrDefault()
    If window IsNot Nothing Then
        window.dgArticleMasterData.DataSource = update
    End If
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```